# How to set width of wrapper in different resolution on my desktop and laptop?

Tags: css, width, media-queries

I have searched Google many times but I can't find the answer I'm looking for.

Example:

My desktop resolution is **1024px**, and I created a website with a width of **1003px**. **1003px** is the maximum width of **1024** resolution before horizontal scrollbars are shown.

So, **what is the max browser width of 768 resolution before horizontal scrollbars are shown?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try making the website using percentage as unit. Its will help you lot for responsive design.

Answer (score 1):

just substract the scrollbar again, wich is usually `16px` on windows platforms. cut off a little more to be sure (special system-settings, other browsers, other operating-systems... up to `20px` is pretty common) - `-21px` like you did in your first example seems to be a nice value.

```
768 - 21 = 747
```

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried media screen

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use Adobe Dreamweaver cs5 for that.